# Android error:R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, html, css

Actually i read the answers but i am in a confused state of what to do now.I am using Eclipse and i get the errors in the lines--

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
Clickhere=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
```

Here is the following code:-

```
package com.example.vaish;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button Clickhere;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Clickhere=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       Clickhere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        }
    });



    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

XML file:
    `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/happy"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Clickhere" />
```

`</RelativeLayout>`

```
   please help!!!
```

i need to get the errors cleared off.

Comment: If you have an error in resource files, this error will show. Pls check your resource files first.

Comment: Check is there any errors in any xml files

Comment: check your activity xml views, any button declare as ``id`` ``button1``

Comment: yes it is declared as button1

Comment: try ``clean``, ``rebuild``, ``gradle update``

Comment: cleaned many times.it also comes as actvity_main cannot be resolved into a type or variable

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project, If R.java is still not build, there can be errors in your project. You can check exact errors in Problems tab as shown in below image:

[image]

Resolve the errors, then clean and build your project.

Comment: i cleaned it .Getting the error "no resource identifier found for xml file"

Comment: Have you added  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to root element in xml file in which you are getting error? If you are using external libs, you can add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto"

Comment: i added this line-xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in Relative layout..do i have to add the line u said???

Comment: What is your XML Layout code, and where you are getting error? Show Error log. You can try adding the line i said.

Answer (score 0):

@Vaishnavi this is not an Error.

Means it is the Error in your XML file...Check XML File First.

Otherwise Try to Clean Your Project OR Build Your Project Properly.

That will solved Your Problem.

Don't Forget (R.) error will never Solve untill you will Remove Your Error from XML File.

Hope this will help you...(:

Answer (score 0):

if `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is line of code which cause of application crash it means you have written incorrect tags or syntax error.

What is your XML Layout code?

Answer (score 0):

``

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Clickhere" />
```

``

Answer (score 0):

Add this import statement

```
import <your.package.name>.R;
```

For instance

```
import com.shivam.cleaner.R;
```